# How to know whether what a user draws covers most of the canvas area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas, where user can write something, and it shows previously saved drawing. But we detected some of them are not using the total canvas area due to some factors. So my questions are:

- Can I detect the area where the user's drawn and make it larger by
  shredding the usused canvas spaces?
- Or, can I detect whether the user
  is using the full canvas area or say more than 60% of it? If yes,
  how? So that I can put an warning to the user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I detect the area where the user's drawn and make it larger by
>   shredding the usused canvas spaces?

By your use of the phrase "shred the undrawn space" I assume you want to scale the existing image larger to fill all the canvas area.

Yes, you can...

**Step#1**

You can use `getImageData` to fetch the pixel color data from your canvas. This data is an array containing the red, green, blue and alpha values of every pixel on the canvas.

```
var pixelData=mainContext.getImageData(0,0,mainCanvas.width,mainCanvas.height).data;
```

The data for canvas pixel[0,0]:

- pixelData[0] is the **red** component of canvas pixel[0,0]
- pixelData[1] is the **green** component of canvas pixel[0,0]
- pixelData[2] is the **blue** component of canvas pixel[0,0]
- pixelData[3] is the **alpha** component of canvas pixel[0,0]

The data for canvas pixel[1,0]:

- pixelData[4] is the **red** component of canvas pixel[1,0]
- pixelData[5] is the **green** component of canvas pixel[1,0]
- pixelData[6] is the **blue** component of canvas pixel[1,0]
- pixelData[7] is the **alpha** component of canvas pixel[1,0]

Use the pixel data to determine the bounding box of your user's opaque pixels. You do this by determining the topmost, leftmost, bottommost and rightmost pixel with alpha>250.

```
var boundLeft,boundTop,boundRight,boundBottom,boundWidth,boundHeight;

function getBounds(){
    boundLeft=1000000;
    boundTop=1000000;
    boundRight=-1000000;
    boundBottom=-1000000;
    //
    var d=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
    //
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i+=4){
        // test the alpha (d[i+3])
        if(d[i+3]>250){
            var px=parseInt(i/4);
            var pixelY=parseInt(px/cw);
            var pixelX=px-pixelY*cw;
            if(pixelX<boundLeft){boundLeft=pixelX;}
            if(pixelX>boundRight){boundRight=pixelX;}
            if(pixelY<boundTop){boundTop=pixelY;}
            if(pixelY>boundBottom){boundBottom=pixelY;}
            boundWidth=boundRight-boundLeft;
            boundHeight=boundBottom-boundTop;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step#2**

Create an in-memory canvas the size of the bounding box.

```
var memCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var memContext=memCanvas.getContext('2d');
memCanvas.width=boundWidth;
memCanvas.height=boundHeight;
```

**Step#3**

Use the clipping version of `context.drawImage` to draw the bounding area from the main canvas to the in-memory canvas.

```
memContext.drawImage(mainCanvas,
    // grab the "used" pixels from the main canvas
    boundLeft,boundTop,boundWidth,boundHeight,
    // and draw those pixels on the in-memory canvas
    0,0,boundWidth,boundHeight
);
```

**Step#4**

(Optionally resize the main canvas to the bounding box size)

```
mainCanvas.width=boundWidth;
mainCanvas.height=boundHeight;
```

Draw the in-memory canvas onto the main canvas

```
mainContext.clearRect(0,0,mainCanvas.width,mainCanvas.height);
mainContext.drawImage(memCanvas,0,0);
```

> Can I detect whether the user is using the full canvas area or say
>   more than 60% of it? If yes, how? So that I can put an warning to the
>   user.

Yes, you can...

Use the same technique above to calculate the boundWidth & boundHeight

Then you can calculate the percentage of "used" canvas using the ratio of the bounding box size vs the canvas size:

```
var percent = (boundWidth*boundHeight) / (mainCanvas.width*mainCanvas.height);
```

**Calculating the new bounding box as the user adds to the drawing**

Rather than using `getImageData` to calculate the new bounding box after each new pixel is drawn by the user, you can instead expand the bounding box if the new pixel is outside the existing bounds:

```
if(newPixelX<leftmost){boundLeft=newPixelX;}
if(newPixelX>rightmost){boundRight=newPixelX;}
if(newPixelY<topmost){boundTop=newPixelY;}
if(newPpixelY>bottommost){boundBottom=newPixelY;}
```

**Example code and Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var leftmost,topmost,rightmost,bottommost;

// load image
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car.png";
function start(){
  //
  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;
  //
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  //
  getBounds();

}


function getBounds(){
  leftmost=1000000;
  topmost=1000000;
  rightmost=-1000000;
  bottommost=-1000000;
  //
  var d=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
  //
  for(var i=0;i<d.length;i+=4){
    // test the alpha (d[i+3])
    if(d[i+3]>250){
      var px=parseInt(i/4);
      var pixelY=parseInt(px/cw);
      var pixelX=px-pixelY*cw;
      if(pixelX<leftmost){leftmost=pixelX;}
      if(pixelX>rightmost){rightmost=pixelX;}
      if(pixelY<topmost){topmost=pixelY;}
      if(pixelY>bottommost){bottommost=pixelY;}
    }
  }
}


function highlightBounds(){
  var previousFill=ctx.fillStyle;
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.05;
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.fillRect(leftmost,topmost,(rightmost-leftmost),(bottommost-topmost));
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
  ctx.fillStyle=previousFill;
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);


  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX,mouseY,3,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  if(mouseX<leftmost){leftmost=mouseX;}
  if(mouseX>rightmost){rightmost=mouseX;}
  if(mouseY<topmost){topmost=mouseY;}
  if(mouseY>bottommost){bottommost=mouseY;}

  var boundsArea=(rightmost-leftmost)*(bottommost-topmost);
  var canvasArea=cw*ch;
  $pct.text(parseInt(boundsArea/canvasArea*100)+'% of canvas area is used');

}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

var $pct=$('#pct');

$('#shred').click(function(){
  var width=rightmost-leftmost;
  var height=bottommost-topmost;
  var memCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
  var memContext=memCanvas.getContext('2d');
  memCanvas.width=width;
  memCanvas.height=height;
  memContext.drawImage(canvas,
                       // grab the "used" pixels from the main canvas
                       leftmost,topmost,width,height,
                       // and draw those pixels on the in-memory canvas
                       0,0,width,height
                      );
  canvas.width=width;
  canvas.height=height;
  ctx.drawImage(memCanvas,0,0);
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=shred>Eliminate outside space</button>
<h4 id=pct>Drag mouse</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I was doing the same technique. But as I am using a js library to manage drawing(jquery.signature.js), it made the things a lot easier. Anyway, many thanks for describing the whole logic in a simple yet superb way. Thanks a lot Mark.